# C# throws a NullReferenceException on return

Tags: c#, .net, nullreferenceexception

I have a problem with a piece of C# .NET 4.7.2 code that consistently throws a NullReferenceException on one machine with Windows 8 (Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0). It works fine on other machines.

I added a lot of logging to track down the issue and it seems to come from the return statement.

Here is the stacktrace:

```
 System.NullReferenceException: Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.
    bei XYZ.Imaging.MipMap.MipMapImage.calculateCurrentMipMapLevel()
    bei XYZ.Imaging.MipMap.MipMapImage.updateMipMapLevel()
    bei System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.fireLayoutUpdateEvent()
    bei System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout()
    bei System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.Process_WM_SIZE(UIElement rootUIElement, IntPtr hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    bei System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.LayoutFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
    bei MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
    bei MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
    bei System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
    bei System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
```

And here the code:

```
        private int calculateCurrentMipMapLevel()
        {
            .......

            log.Info("calculateCurrentMipMapLevel: viewportRectangle= " + viewportRectangle);
            log.Info("calculateCurrentMipMapLevel: mipmap= " + mipmap);
            int newLevel = mipmap.CalculateLevel(viewportRectangle);

            log.Info("calculateCurrentMipMapLevel: newLevel= " + newLevel);
            return newLevel;
        }
```

The last log messages before the crash are:

```
 INFO  ] - calculateCurrentMipMapLevel: viewportRectangle= 0;0;7021;6415,33920234175
 INFO  ] - calculateCurrentMipMapLevel: mipmap= XYZ.Imaging.MipMap.MipMap
 INFO  ] - calculateCurrentMipMapLevel: newLevel= 3
```

I also decompiled the code using .NET reflector and got this code:

```
        ......
        log.Info("calculateCurrentMipMapLevel: viewportRectangle= " + view.ToString(), Array.Empty<object>());
        XYZ.Imaging.MipMap.MipMap map2 = this.mipmap;
        if (map2 != null)
        {
            text6 = map2.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            XYZ.Imaging.MipMap.MipMap local7 = map2;
            text6 = null;
        }
        log.Info("calculateCurrentMipMapLevel: mipmap= " + text6, Array.Empty<object>());
        int num = this.mipmap.CalculateLevel(view);
        log.Info("calculateCurrentMipMapLevel: newLevel= " + num.ToString(), Array.Empty<object>());
        return num;
```

I have no idea how this NullReferenceException could be raised and I have no idea how to investigate this further.
Does anyone have any hints?
.....

EDIT 1:
I'm now able to reproduce this on my developer machine with Windows 10.
Very strange thing is:
When I run the application from VS2019 as Release build it works!
When I go into the folder of the build output and run the application from there the issue happens.

Very strange to me...

Comment: What about lines before the first log statement? Or you have log statement at first line of `calculateCurrentMipMapLevel`?

Comment: I would start by trying to reproduce it in as small a program as you possibly can. You're likely to find the issue during that process - and if you don't, you'll have a [mcve] that you can edit into the question. (Are you sure it's *that* call to `calculateCurrentMipMapLevel` that's throwing the exception? If you have multiple calls, one could be logging the successful result, and another failing very early.) Also, is the exception throw if you run the app in the debugger?

Comment: Is `calculateCurrentMipMapLevel()` part of a recursion?

Comment: Why are you using Reflector to decompile **your own code**?

Comment: Could issue have to do with the graphic card.  Imaging is going to use the graphic modes supported by the graphic card.  So the default graphics mode settings may be different on machine.  Another possibility is the motherboard driver may need updating.  Windows updates does not update the vendor specific dlls.  So yo may need to go to the mother board vendor and update the dll.  Also find out which graphic chip is being used on motherboard and download the graphic chip driver.

Comment: @jdweng how does this question related to graphic card?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski : Imaging default settings are gotten from the graphic card.

Comment: @Evk there are some calculations before the code I posted, but since the logfile contains the logs in the code above I assumed it ran correctly.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride there is no recursion involved

Comment: @IanKemp I wanted to rule out any issue in optimization.

I have an update.. See in the question description.

Comment: Your log file can contain logs from _previous_ invocation of this function. Then on next invocation something at the beginning (before first log statement) can throw this exception. Stack trace seems to suggest this function is called as part of layout, so can be called many times in quick succession (for example on resize)

Comment: @Evk you are right.
It is called multiple times in a row... Thanks for the hint. I will try to dig into this.
Do you have any idea how I can distinguish the different calls?

Comment: Add a counter and increment it on each call? Then include it in the log statement. But you also need to add log statements at the beginning of function